# Rails_admin, change order of columns in list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

In rails_admin list shows all available columns of model according to how columns are ordered in database:

[image: pic]

However, I want different order in list page. I want first `name` and then other fields in table.

Is it even possible? There are no mentions in documentation of rails_admin about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read about ordering of fields here: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Fields#inclusion

In case your model is called User, create a new configuration file `config/initializers/rails_admin/user.rb`

with the following content:

```
if User.table_exists?
  RailsAdmin.config User do
    list do
      # simply adding fields by their names (order will be maintained)
      include_fields :name, :id, :created_at, :updated_at, :version, :shopping_malls
    end
  end
end
```

Let me know if this works out!

Comment: It prompts "undefined method `defined' for nil:NilClass" if used with a dynamic field

Answer (score 3):

The documentation has changed. Create `rails_admin` folder in initializers. Add an `.rb` file with your model name to that folder: `config/initializers/rails_admin/`.

Then add columns that you want to leave in the order you want them to be shown.

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.model 'YourModelName' do
    list do
      field :name
      field :version
    end
  end
end
```

This would show only "name" and "version" columns in the list view.

Answer (score 0):

In app/admin/item.rb you can do this.

`index do
    column :Name 
    column :id
    column :created_at
 end`

This will give you column with Name, id and created_at.

Comment: will it affect to `list` action ?

Comment: No it wont affect your list action,its only in admin side.i hope you have admin/list.rb file where you can add following code.

Comment: Is it activeadmin gem you are mentioning? I use rails_admin gem

Comment: if so than you can use this way.

`RailsAdmin.config do |config|

  config.model 'Team' do

    list do

      field :name
      field :created_at
    end
  end
end`